# How can I combine three 2D matrices into a 3D matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, concatenation

```
a = [1 2 3;
     4 5 6;
     7 8 9];

b = [10 11 12;
     13 14 15;
     16 17 18;
    ];

c = [19 20 21;
     22 23 24;
     25 26 27;
    ];
```

I want to combine the above 2D matrices into a 3D matrix `mat` so that I can access them in the following way,

```
>> mat(:, :, 1)
ans = 
[1 2 3
 4 5 6
 7 8 9]

>> mat(:, :, 2) 
ans = 
[10 11 12
 13 14 15
 16 17 18]

>> mat(:,:,3)
ans = 
[19 20 21
 22 23 24
 25 26 27]
```

I tried the following,

```
mat = [a, b, c];
```

But, it actually doesn't work.

So, **how can I achieve that?**

Comment: In addition to the answers read the documentation associated with `cat` to get more ideas of ways to combine things.

Comment: @hbaderts: Hmm, wonder why that didn't show up on the "Related" sidebar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it as follows using explicit matrix indexing:

```
mat(:,:,1) = a;
mat(:,:,2) = b;
mat(:,:,3) = c;
```

`mat = [a, b, c];` will create a `3x9` matrix.

Answer (score 5):

Square brackets `[]` are for horizontal and vertical concatenation of matrices. You can use the [`cat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html) function for concatenating along higher dimensions:

```
mat = cat(3, a, b, c);
```

More info can be found [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/creating-and-concatenating-matrices.html#f1-85019).

Comment: what is wrong with `m7913d`'s answer?

Comment: @anonymous: Nothing. That's just another way to achieve the same thing.

Comment: @anonymous This is a nice alternative, shorter, but somewhat harder to remember.